# Need a way/blocks to trigger a switch and held the result in Simulink\Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

A Host vehicle (HV) is doing lane change (as shown in the image below). Once HV crossing the lane, it is necessary to swap lanes assignment at a time where lane change happens. For example, here, before lane change, left lane == lane label 3. After lane change, left lane == lane label 1. The request is that once vehicle entering the zone, change the lane assignment. (We know lane width, offset distances from lanes and HVs)

[HV lane change model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBR6h.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a simulink block which calls a matlab function? Function can be something like:

```
if position > a && position < b
    left_lane = label 1;
if position > b && position < c
    left_lane = label 2;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for response I found another way out !! Yet appreciate the support!

Comment: Can you please post your method as an answer to your own question?

Comment: I used altogether different logic which was when anyone of the (left or right)camera sensor detects lane change we swap every lane label.